# IIS metrics with Windows exporter

Tags: iis, prometheus, metrics

The Prometheus windows exporter can export IIS metrics if specifically stated when starting the service. On the main documentation page of this project, you can find the specifics about exported IIS metrics: [IIS Docs](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/blob/master/docs/collector.iis.md)

There are no example and no comments about what a metric is supposed to tell you and I'm not really familiar with this. I need to understand if these metrics can help me discovering the amount of memory (RAM) being used by each app pool active on a specific machine or if I have to write a custom exporter.

I have the exporter already active with IIS metrics on the machine I need to monitor and I already tried some queries with these metrics:

- `windows_iis_worker_file_cache_memory_bytes`
- `windows_iis_worker_file_cache_max_memory_bytes`

But can't tell if these are what I'm looking for. Can anyone point me in the right direction? And please, if these metrics already do the job I need, reply with the correct query.

Comment: how did you activate it to start collecting IIS metrics?